# Having problems with clickable links

Tags: php, mysql

So here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<a href =\"vicevi.php?id=$row[id]\">".$row['Title'];"</a>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo nl2br($row["VicText"]);
  echo "<hr>";
}
```

And I get the link `vicevi.php?id=x` (*x=any number*) but it doesn't open specific id. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: try it as `{$row['id']}`, or use concatenation like you did with the content of the anchor, or use `sprintf` to make it even cleaner...

Comment: You have an extra semi colon `$row['Title']**;**`

Comment: And theres that `;` that PeeHaa mentions :-)

Comment: `"<a href ='vicevi.php?id=".$row[id]."'>".$row['Title']."</a>";`

Comment: It still doesn't prints out just that specific id.. It goes on the link and nothing happens.
http://localhost/projects/Free%20HTML5%20Template%20Design%20Company/site/vicevi.php?id=24 but i get every post and not the specific one

Answer (score 1):

`echo "<a href =\"vicevi.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">".$row['Title'] . "</a>";`

Besides the `$row[id]` problem you had a `;` extra.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href =\"vicevi.php?id=".$row['id']."\>".$row['Title']."</a>";
```